# (Workaround) In Unity, how can I have a Game View not pixalated even in scale is x1?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, rendering, display

Hello Stack overflow people,

I am new here. 
I've started to use Unity by doing one of there tutorial for a 2D RPG game.
The Tutorial is Ruby's Adventure. 
I am in the fifth part of the Tutorial where it is only about decorating the world and a weird thing happpen suddenly to my Game View Display.

Issue:
* Even though my Scene view is clean my Game View suddently got super pixelated (cf. Views pics)
* I tried to play with the scale of the game view and even in scale 1 the view is still super pixalated
* In Free Aspect Drop down list, Low Resolution Aspect Ratio is checked but the option is always greyed out

Thanks everyone for your time,

Best Regards,

Pascal

PS: 
* my Unity version: 2019.1.0f2
* my project: Ruby's Adventure Tutorial

Comment: I don't have an answer but if you're curious you can read what the [Low Resolution Aspect Ratio](https://forum.unity.com/threads/game-view-low-resolution-aspect-ratios.545913/#post-3813361) means.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help Iggy.

.. so I still don't know why my Game Mode & Play Mode are pixalated even at scale 1.
It could be because of Low Resolution Aspect Ratio being checked.
But I am not even sure, since I never played or never done something about Free Aspect Settings.

BUT I've found a workaround.
If I've turned on the MAXIMIZE ON PLAY option. By doing so, when I go to Play Mode the rendering is ok (cf. pictures).
[MaximizeOnPlay-OFF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16GXw.jpg)
[MaximizeOnPlay-ON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfRrC.jpg)

So I will moved forward with that.
To be continued...

Hope it helps,

Pascal